# Form framework for inputs specified by custom popup window

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP based form.  For many of our inputs, the user clicks an html which created a custom popup window with a "mini-form".  When the user clicks on the submit button, the values from the "mini-form" are sent to the main form to hidden inputs using JavaScript.  This can become complicated to do, especially with validation and other complications.  I know there are a million PHP frameworks for forms, but I can't find one to deal with these situations.

Does anyone have advice?

Comment: How about creating CSS overlay instead of opening new window? This way the scope is not changed, you rather "enlarge" mini form.

Comment: Is that the same as using dialogs in jQuery UI?

Comment: It can be done using jQuery UI dialogs as well.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are opening new form using var win = window.open() now using the win reference you might be populating the actual forms data. This is old good approach which is been working well from long time.

If this is correct Then I think that if you would really want to do it in better way you should start with JQuery UI.

Comment: Exactly what I was doing.  It just gets a little tedious working out all the javascript for transferring variables between the two windows.